# How do i make an array which is a class object and has a compile time size?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, memory, compile-time

I'm new at this and haven't done much, but I'm really stuck on making a compile-time sized array, which is a class object. And maybe there's a way to save all the information from file, while occupying less of memory? Here's a bit of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Beer
{
public:
    string name;
    string rating;
    string country;
    string alc;
    string type;
};

int main()   //Function uses ''bytes of stack/exceeds analyze:stacksize '16384'. 
             //Consider moving some data to heap
{
    ifstream file("beer.txt");

    if (!file.good())
    {
        cout << "Error. File was not found." << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        int count;
        string line;
        ifstream file("beer.txt");
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; !file.eof(); i++)
        {
            getline(file, line);
            count++;
        }

        const int SIZE = count;  //<- this is the place i'm struggling with

        Beer allBeers[SIZE];     //expression must have a constant value
        Beer currentBeer;  

        for (int i = 0; !file.eof(); i++)
        {
            getline(file, currentBeer.name, '\t');
            getline(file, currentBeer.rating, '\t');
            getline(file, currentBeer.country, '\t');
            getline(file, currentBeer.alc, '\t');
            getline(file, currentBeer.type, '\n');

            allBeers[i] = currentBeer;
        }


    }
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **Why** do you want a compile-time array? Especially since you don’t have the information at compile-time. You’re reading them from a file at runtime.

Comment: That big else is redundant

Comment: Please define limits (always). I.e. what is the smallest allowed input size, and the largest input size. What is the max length of beers.txt --  1GB? More? Suddenly, the stack based array becomes not a good idea.

Comment: When learning start from some real life requirements. For example database like requirements. I.e. "show all bears with rating 5 and country 'UK' ".

Comment: I obviously meant "beers" not "bears" ... cheers :)

Comment: i'm actually doing something alike, just using more like a filter, for sorting beer ratings according to it's type, country, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *main* problem with your code is in the following two lines:

```cpp
    const int SIZE = count;  //<- this is the place i'm struggling with
    Beer allBeers[SIZE];     //expression must have a constant value
```

Now, although `SIZE` is defined as `const` it is ***not*** a *compile-time* constant! Further, arrays in `C++` need dimensions that are *compile-time* constants. (Your `const` qualifier means only that, once initialized, the value of `SIZE` cannot be changed.)

The simple, "old-style-C++" way of working around this is to declare `allBeers` as a *pointer* and use the `new` operator to create the 'array buffer' at run-time (when the *actual* value of `SIZE` is known):

```cpp
    const int SIZE = count;  // Don't really need this, now - could just use "count"
    Beer* allBeers = new Beer[SIZE]; // You can still use allBeers[i] to access!
```

But, here, you shoud be sure to execute `delete[] allBeers;` when you're done with the array/buffer.

A more modern approach would be to use the `std::vector` type, in which case freeing memory takes care of itself when the object goes out of scope:

```cpp
    const size_t SIZE = size_t(count);
    std::vector<Beer> allBeers(SIZE);
```

Again, you can then access using `allBeers[i]`.

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: PS: "Beer" and "memory" are terms that seldom work well together!  ‎

Comment: Haha, only if you put brain between them :D Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

If you don't know the size of an array during compile time, just use a `std::vector`:

```cpp
#include <vector>

// ...

// const int SIZE = count;  // you don't need this anymore
std::vector<Beer> allBeers;     

// ...

allBeers.push_back(currentBeer); // to append it to your 'array'
```

`vector`s behave very similar to arrays, but when using `push_back` they 'grow' if needed. Notice that they might reserve a little more memory than is necessary so they don't have to grow every time you call `push_back`. To free this reserved memory you can call `shrink_to_fit` once afterwards.

If you don't want to use `shrink_to_fit` you can also make the `vector` precisely the size you need beforehand using

```cpp
const int SIZE = count;
std::vector<Beer> allBeers;  
allBeers.reserve(SIZE);
```

Comment: How come when I use vectors, I get the error that 'std::vector':'Beer' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the size at compile time, then you should use a `std::vector` instead.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

`#include <vector>`

And then

```
std::vector<Beer> allBeers;
```

Later, to add a beer:

```
allBeers.push_back(currentBeer);
```

Comment: Thanks!! vector was what I've been missing :))